# Angular and typescript: Change text and global color variable in a ngfor-loop

Tags: typescript, ionic3, ngfor

I have an toggle-button for 'watching' and 'watch' in my ngfor-Loop for all my feedItem:

```
<button ion-button small icon-left [color]="primary" (click)="toggleNamedColor(feedItem)">
        {{feedItem.watchlist}}
</button>
```

The values for feedItem.watchlist are false or true.

What is the easiest way to change the global variable 'color' and the text to :

feedItem.watchlist === false -> color: success, text: watching and
feedItem.watchlist === true -> color: primary, text: watch

Thank you for your hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular using `[]` in attributes allows you to pass JavaScript expressions to the element in order to dynamically have attribute values.

You could try to do something like this

```
<button ion-button small icon-left [color]="feedItem.watchlist ? 'primary' : 'success'" (click)="toggleNamedColor(feedItem)">
        {{feedItem.watchlist}}
</button>
```

Ultimately, if the logic for the value is too complex you could also pass a function to have the logic in the controller (aka component).

```
<button ion-button small icon-left [color]="getButtonColor(feedItem.watchlist)" (click)="toggleNamedColor(feedItem)">
        {{feedItem.watchlist}}
</button>
```